# Drag and Drop with ListView WPF failed using ItemSource

Tags: wpf, drag, listviewitem

I have `ListView` with ItemSource:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> List;
```

And my `ListView` is full with several object.

Now i want to add the option to change my `ListViewItems` via darg so i found this solution: https://fxmax.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/wpf/

And after add the code inside my project i only have one problem that cause crash:

```
private void BeginDrag(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView listView = this.listView;
            ListViewItem listViewItem = FindAnchestor<ListViewItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);

            if (listViewItem == null)
                return;

            // get the data for the ListViewItem
            MyObject name = (MyObject)listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listViewItem);

            //setup the drag adorner.
            InitialiseAdorner(listViewItem);

            //add handles to update the adorner.
            listView.PreviewDragOver += listView_PreviewDragOver;
            listView.DragLeave += listView_DragLeave;
            listView.DragEnter += listView_DragEnter;

            DataObject data = new DataObject("myFormat", name);
            DragDropEffects de = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this.listView, data, DragDropEffects.Move);

            //cleanup 
            listView.PreviewDragOver -= listView_PreviewDragOver;
            listView.DragLeave -= listView_DragLeave;
            listView.DragEnter -= listView_DragEnter;

            if (_adorner != null)
            {
                AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listView).Remove(_adorner);
                _adorner = null;
            }
        }
```

At this line:

```
DragDropEffects de = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this.listView, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid while
>   ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with
>   ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.'

I can see that is because i am using `ItemSource` but dont know what to change.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please provide a MCVE when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the sample code that you linked on the other site, I did some changes and was able to fix the solution to work with ItemsSource.

The changes done are as follows:
 - in MainWindow.xaml

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
              x:Name="listView"
```

- in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 private void ListViewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
        {
            MyObject name = e.Data.GetData("myFormat") as MyObject;
            ListViewItem listViewItem = FindAnchestor<ListViewItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
            ObservableCollection<MyObject> myArray = listView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<MyObject>;

            if (listViewItem != null && listViewItem.DataContext is MyObject)
            {
                MyObject dropLocation = (MyObject)listViewItem.DataContext;
                int index = myArray.IndexOf(dropLocation);

                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    myArray.Remove(name);
                    myArray.Insert(index, name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myArray.Remove(name);
                myArray.Add(name);
            }
        }
    }
```

...

```
private void BeginDrag(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listView = this.listView;
        ListViewItem listViewItem =
            FindAnchestor<ListViewItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);

        if (listViewItem == null)
            return;

        MyObject selectedItem = (MyObject)listViewItem.DataContext;

        //setup the drag adorner.
        InitialiseAdorner(listViewItem);

        //add handles to update the adorner.
        listView.PreviewDragOver += ListViewDragOver;
        listView.DragLeave += ListViewDragLeave;
        listView.DragEnter += ListViewDragEnter;

        DataObject data = new DataObject("myFormat", selectedItem);
        DragDropEffects de = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this.listView, data, DragDropEffects.Move);

        //cleanup 
        listView.PreviewDragOver -= ListViewDragOver;
        listView.DragLeave -= ListViewDragLeave;
        listView.DragEnter -= ListViewDragEnter;

        if (_adorner != null)
        {
            AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listView).Remove(_adorner);
            _adorner = null;
        }
    }
```

The changes themselves use the concept of **MyObject** as the payload, instead of string, and the ObservableCollection as the array where you do the changes, instead of the IEnumerable.

Hope this solves your problem.